# Jquery Mobile taphold on img tag and Android 4.1 mobile Save Dialog?

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using the following code,

```
$(document).delegate('div[data-role*="page"]', 'pageshow', function () {
    $(document).delegate('#imageId', 'taphold', function (evt) {
    });
});
```

It works but also show me a Save Dialog prompt. Tried,

```
img  {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none !important; 
}
```

and return false but nothing works. tested on Android 4.1 Google Chrome and Default Browser

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here ? And works? coz i didnt get u at all.

Comment: @SathyaRaj, Let's say you want to use a Key in your web app. But what if the same key is used by browser. For example, right click. We you easily disable the browser right click. Similarly, when tap hold your on a picture in Andriod, it will shows you a Save Dialog, I want to disable this browser feature. Because I am using this feature.

Comment: $('#imageId').disableSelection(); can u try this ?

Comment: @SathyaRaj, It's for Jquery UI instead of Jquery Mobile

Comment: have you tried using js like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413683/disabling-the-context-menu-on-long-taps-on-android from what i get is you want disable the default android action and use your functionality like preventDefault(); rite? I 2 hav not done this before.. hope this might helps.

Comment: @SathyaRaj, it works but now the taphold is not triggering