# preventDefault on touchstart without preventing scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault, touchstart

There are similar questions to this one, but the solutions either involve another library or using a click event instead - I wondered if it was feasible to achieve without a library.

I'm using a touchstart event on an image to detect a tap of 1.5s, which then reloads said image. However on most mobile devices when you press and hold on an image for a period of time, it displays a popup to ask if you would like to save/copy the image, which I would like to prevent.

`preventDefault()` does the trick, but ignores scrolling on the image too (as expected).

What would be the best way to also allow scrolling on the image?

Example code:

```
$('#the-image').bind('touchstart', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //detects long tap, then reloads etc
});
```

iOS has a CSS property (`-webkit-touch-callout:none`) that works fine, but will not work on non-iOS devices.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try `-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;` if you can use **CSS.**

And a nice trick would be `node.ontouchstart = node.onclick;` so it thinks you're using a computer mouse.

See [Disabling the context menu on long taps on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413683/disabling-the-context-menu-on-long-taps-on-android)

Comment: The 'absorbEvent_' function calls the `preventDefault()` method which unfortunately disables scrolling on the element

Comment: @George Unfortunately.