# disable long click context menu on a web page (Android 4.4 - Firefox 34.0)

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, firefox

Like the title says I'd like to disable the context menu after long click on pretty much every thing on my web page. This said, I still want all link to be active even if the context will not show up. One more thing, this will only be use in a local network where clients will be using the same tablets, OS and Web browser.

I've been trying this [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413683/disabling-the-context-menu-on-long-taps-on-android) but doesn't give me satisfaction cause it breaks the links. and other answers doesn't work for me.
I'm no javascript pro so I may be missing some points...

the CSS -webkit-touch-callout: none !important; do not work on firefox if I'm not wrong.

So how to achieve this? CSS? HTML? JAVASCRIPT?

Thanks for your cooperation ;)

**UPDATE**

I've found this code which create the new contextmenu and prevent default but....

```
<script>
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
        alert("You've tried to open context menu"); //here you draw your own menu
        e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
} else {
    document.attachEvent('oncontextmenu', function() {
        alert("You've tried to open context menu");
        window.event.returnValue = false;
    });
}
</script>
```

... the original context menu still opens after the new one :(

Comment: instead of just downvote, can you comment...? and tell me why? I'll be happy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is good, but you were mislead by the comment. You did not draw any new context menu, so your code will only stop the `contextmenu` event.

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```