# Disable right click for mobile (IOS & ANDROID)

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit, contextmenu

**So i have this code on my site to disable right click for computers.**

`<body oncontextmenu="return false" onselectstart="return false" ondragstart="return false">
<body oncontextmenu="return false;">`

**But I cant seem to get these to work for mobile devices:**

`.disableSave {
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    -webkit-touch-callout:none;
}`

**and**

`oncontextmenu="return false;";

`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disabling the context menu on long taps on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413683/disabling-the-context-menu-on-long-taps-on-android)

Comment: Tad, it worked perfect, i liked it was fully coded too, for someone that cant code so well it was a bit confusing plugging and playing lol, but yea now ill be working on disabling screenshots lol, bro thank you again!

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad I could help. Happy coding!