# How to disable only long press on youtube video in react-native-youtube-iframe

Tags: react-native

I have used react-native-youtube-iframe to play youtube videos in my react native app. I want to disable long-press on youtube videos.

Comment: facing same issue. anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: @MaheshGawhane, `onContextMenu={(e) => e.preventDefault()}` is working?

Answer (score 0):

From **GitHub documentation**, I solved by using.

#### Removing context menu on long-press:

Wrap the *YoutubePlayer* in a View that has `pointerEvents="none"` to disable app touch-events to the player.

Then react-native's [Pressable API](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable) or any of the touchables to intercept presses.

```
    <Pressable
      onPress={() => {
        // handle or ignore
      }}
      onLongPress={() => {
        // handle or ignore
      }}>
    
      <View pointerEvents="none">
        <YoutubePlayer (...) />
      </View>
    
    </Pressable>
```

Source: https://lonelycpp.github.io/react-native-youtube-iframe/remove-context-share

**Another Way** is using `onContextMenu={(e) => e.preventDefault()`:

```
<div onContextMenu={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>

    <YoutubePlayer (...) />

</div>
```

Comment: Using this we can't touch Youtube players, play/pause. If we give buttons for play/pause then what about Fullscreen mode. Is there any function or event to change video to Fullscreen mode using button?

Comment: Can you please Try Disabling context menu on whole screen: (see 170 up votes answer in) https://stackoverflow.com/a/28748222/15932042

(It is temporary fix, didn't tested)
I saw few comments (including yours) in GitHub, I didn't found exact solution.

Comment: not working this as well

Comment: @MaheshGawhane, `onContextMenu={(e) => e.preventDefault()}` is working?