# HTML Mobile On Text Highlight Hide "Copy, Look up, Share..." Menu But Still Allow Text Highlight

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, addeventlistener, highlight

I am following [this](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-code-an-inline-sharing-menu--cms-26933) tutorial to create my own highlight contextual menu like medium.com. This works but on mobile devices, my custom highlight menu is hidden because the device's custom software hides it. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVoM7.jpg) is an image of the problem:

[Image Of Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVoM7.jpg)

My code:

```
document.body.addEventListener('pointerup', function(){
   // Shows my custom highlight menu
});
```

So what can I do? I want to hide this highlight menu on mobile devices because it hides my custom one as shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVoM7.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

Try checking this question out: [Disabling the context menu on long taps on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413683/disabling-the-context-menu-on-long-taps-on-android#answer-28748222)

An answer that worked for me was by bbsimonbb, and his answer was:

```
<style>
html, body { 
  -webkit-touch-callout: none !important; /* disable selection/Copy of UIWebView */
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* disable the IOS popup when long-press on a link */
}
</style>
<script>
window.oncontextmenu = function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     event.stopPropagation();
     return false;
};
</script>
```

If you use Jquery you can also add this to the code above:

```
<script>
$("body").bind('taphold', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```